# Plane vertices from normals and centroid

Tags: geometry, regression

I am trying to visualize a best fit plane for a set of points which is defined by the normals and the centroid.

I have to find the boundary vertices of the plane given the extent of the plane. Is there any easy algorithm which can help in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm) and do whatever regression, e.g. [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) you like.